# Trying to send messages to Telegram from a text file

Tags: python, twitter, telegram

I have made one script in python, and what it does is it checks Elon Musks twitter for new tweets, and then saves it to a text file in a list 1,2,3

I now want to make another script that also uses a text file, it compares text file 1 to text file 2.  if the new text file, doesnt have the same most recent tweet as file 1 it sends it to telegram, and saves it to its own file.  Currently all I have for the second script is

```
import requests

def telegram_bot_sendtext(bot_message):
    
    bot_token = 'xxx'
    bot_chatID = 'xxx'
    send_text = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + bot_token + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + bot_chatID + '&parse_mode=Markdown&text=' + bot_message

    response = requests.get(send_text)

    return response.json()
    

test = telegram_bot_sendtext("Testing Telegram bot")
print(test)
```

Just the basic hello world tutorial.  I thought there would be a youtube video I could find for something like this, maybe its not as simple as I thought? --*(o.O)*--

I am incredibly new to programming, and thought this would be a fun start to data analysis.  Any help is appreciated!

Edit:  The other code is

```
import requests
import twint

c = twint.Config()
c.Limit = 20
c.Username = "elonmusk"
c.Pandas = True

twint.run.Search(c)

Tweets_df = twint.storage.panda.Tweets_df
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code from other script as well.

Comment: import twint import os search elonmusk test.csv

Comment: Ill get the Exact code when I get home, but that is pretty much it.  Just using twint to scrape twitter, and save to either a txt, or csv.

Comment: @WiLL_K   import requests
import twint 

c = twint.Config()
c.Limit = 20
c.Username = "elonmusk"
c.Pandas = True

twint.run.Search(c)

Tweets_df = twint.storage.panda.Tweets_df